# Git is not copied to new directory in Intellij

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I copied my project folder to a newly created directory. By using "refactor -> copy" on my project files I wanted to assure that my git commit history is also copied to the new directory. This did not work.

How can I copy my project as well as my git repository and my commit history to a new directory?

Comment: Everything about your Git history lives in the .git folder.  Did you not copy that over?

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. I thought Intellijs refactor option would copy my .git folder over. But it did not. So I created a new .git repository in the new location (with Intellij -> import into version control), deleted the .git folder and copied my old .git folder in.